# If $p,q,r$ be lengths of perpendiculars from vertices of triangle $ABC$ on any line, prove $a^2(p-q)(p-r)+b^2(q-r)(q-p)+c^2(r-p)(r-q)=4\Delta^2$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, triangles, area

Let :
$$A:=(x_1,y_1),$$
$$B:=(x_2,y_2),$$
$$C:=(x_3,y_3)$$
be the vertices of the triangle $ABC$. Consider an arbitrary straight line in perpendicular form $x\cos \theta + y\sin \theta - t = 0$. Then the lengths of the perpendiculars from the vertices of the triangle are:
$$p=x_1\cos \theta + y_1\sin \theta - t,$$
$$q=x_2\cos \theta + y_2\sin \theta - t,$$
$$r=x_3\cos \theta + y_3\sin \theta - t.$$
Moreover, the lengths of the sides of the triangle are:
$$a^2=(x_3-x_2)^2+(y_3-y_2)^2,$$
$$b^2=(x_1-x_3)^2+(y_1-y_3)^2,$$
$$c^2=(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2.$$
Using the above values I tried to evaluate the LHS to prove the desired result, but that way is too tedious. Can anyone suggest me a better proof?

Comment: Here $∆$ is the area of the triangle.

Comment: I think you are probably using "signed lengths," and if so, then this should be clearly stated in the problem statement.  That is, you set one direction to be positive and the other negative.  If the straight line cuts through the triangle and you are not using signed length, then I am afraid that the claim is false.

Comment: @Batominovski, the actual problem (as mentioned in the textbook) considers any straight line and tells nothing about whether the lengths are signed or not.

Comment: Then, I suggest that you added "signed lengths" anyhow because the problem is false without using signed lengths.

Comment: @JeanMarie This is because the perpendiculars are not the altitudes of the triangle.  Let me restate the problem.  There is a triangle $ABC$ and there is a fixed straight line $l$.  Project $A$, $B$, and $C$ orthogonally onto $l$ to get  the points $X$, $Y$, and $Z$, respectively.  Then, $p$, $q$, and $r$ are the signed lengths $AX$, $BY$, and $CZ$.

Comment: @Batominovski Thanks ! I hadn't well read the question ! Sorry. I erase my stupid remarks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint.**  Let $$f(u,v,w):=(v-w)^2(p-q)(p-r)+(w-u)^2(q-r)(q-p)+(u-v)^2(r-p)(r-q)\,.$$ Observe that 
$$\begin{align}f(u,v,w)&=\big((v-w)p\big)^2+\big((w-u)q\big)^2+\big((u-v)r\big)^2\\&\phantom{aaaaa}+2\,\big((w-u)q\big)\,\big((u-v)r\big)+2\,\big((u-v)r\big)\,\big((v-w)p\big)+2\,\big((v-w)p\big)\,\big((w-u)q\big)\,.\end{align}$$
Therefore,
$$f(u,v,w)=\Big(\det\big(M(u,v,w)\big)\Big)^2\,,$$ where $$M(u,v,w):=\begin{bmatrix}1&p&u\\1&q&v\\1&r&w\end{bmatrix}\,.$$

Comment: I think the parameters $u,v,w$ are the three vertices of the triangle.

Comment: Not quite.  Treat the straight line as the $x$-axis.  Then the coordinates of the points $A$, $B$, and $C$ are $(u,p)$, $(v,q)$, and $(w,r)$, respectively.  Then your expression equals $f(p,q,r)+f(u,v,w)$, but of course, $f(p,q,r)=0$.

Comment: I don't see how the parameters can be employed, for defining $v-w:=a$,$w-u:=b$,$u-v:=c$ gives an unexpected result , $a+b+c=0$. Moreover, we need to eliminate $p,q,r$ from the expression of $\det A$.

Comment: That is not what I did.  You note that $a^2=(q-r)^2+(v-w)^2$, $b^2=(r-p)^2+(w-u)^2$, and $c^2=(p-q)^2+(u-v)^2$.  And the absolute value of $\det\big(M(u,v,w)\big)$ is precisely twice the area of the triangle with vertices $A(u,p)$, $B(v,q)$, and $C(w,r)$.  (I changed the name of the matrix to $M$ so that we don't confuse it with the point $A$.)

Comment: Nice solution.......